# When can we integrate a series function

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, functions, definite-integrals

Say we have a series

$\sum_{n=501}^{1000} 1/x = 0.6926...$

$\int_{500}^{1000}\frac1x dx=0.6934...$

Here integration seems to work for us, but that doesn't always happen

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{2^x}=1$

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac1{2^x}=1.4$

How can we know when to integrate a series for desired results, can we change a series to a different function so when we integrate that function we'll get the sum of the series

Let's say

$\int_{a-1}^{b}f(x)dx=\sum_{n=a}^{b}\frac1{2^x}$,

can we find that $f(x)$?, we'll just integrate it and we'll have our answer

Comment: What does *“integration seems to work for us”* mean? In your first example, the sum and the integral have different values.

Comment: They're approximately equal

Comment: The error is related to the first term in the series.  Namely $$\frac{1}{501} = 0.002; \quad \frac{1}{2^0} = 0.5$$Your textbook probably has a section called "integral test" where such approximations are used.

Comment: @GEdgar the integral test is for finding if the infinite series is convergent or divergent,

Comment: True, but the proof of the integral test involves inequalities showing how close the sum and the integral are.

Comment: The steeper the function, the worse the integral approximation is. $1/x$ is quite flat on $[500,1000]$, while $2^x$ is much less flat near $0$.

Comment: @GEdgar Hmm I see, $S_n=u_1+L$ but if we apply it to $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac1{2^x}+f(1)=1.94...$ which is better than 1.44 but still....

Comment: Look up [Euler-Maclaurin summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)